# What could I use to edit graph-based data?

Tags: graphs

I'm looking for software I can use to visualise and edit a graph. I have a bunch of nodes and edges with attributes on them, and I'd like to be able to:

- display the graph visually, with the way nodes and edges are displayed defined according to their attributes. I don't mind if I need to define this in code, in a configuration file or in a GUI.
- Edit the graph, then export it into a format that's not too difficult to read programmatically.

The closest I've found is [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed), which comes *so close* to doing what I want between the "Manage Custom Properties" and "Properties Mapper" options, but the Properties Mapper isn't as flexible as I'd like (e.g. I'd like to be able to concatenate two properties for the labels on nodes), and it doesn't automatically apply (so if I add new nodes/edges or change the properties of existing ones, I have to go back into the Properties Mapper and click Apply every time).

I'd also like to be able to store the style definitions (e.g. the Properties Mapper stuff) in a separate file from the actual graph, but that's not a necessity.

I'm looking for something that runs on the Web, Windows **or** macOS; ideally it shouldn't be *exclusively* macOS-only though. Free would be ideal but I can probably get approval to buy something that's no more than a few hundred AUD.

Comment: By "Edit the Graph" do you mean change the display properties of the graph or change the data that underlies the graph?

Comment: @SteveBarnes Edit the data attached to the nodes and edges.